# Should I add a double quote to c# variable for adding a css class in razor?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to conditionally display css class.

I have a if statement like:

```
@if(a > 5)
{
  specialBackground = "background: green;";
}
```

Then in my html table, I have:

```
<table>
 <tr style=@specialBackground>
 </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is: Several days ago, Without adding a double quote to @specialBackground, I can see the row background color is green. `<tr style=@specialBackground>`.

But today, I need to add a double quote to @specialBackground, `<tr style="@specialBackground">`, then I can see row background color is green. I believe I did not change other code.

My question is:

1. How can I find the reason why sometimes without adding double quote works, but sometimes not.
2. Should I add a double quote in this case?
3. If I did not add the double quote to @specialBackground, I can put the breakpoint in `if(a > 5)`. If I did not add the double quote to this variable, I only can put the breakpoint in `specialBackground = "background: green;";` Why?

Thanks for helping me out. I debug for 3 hours, but no idea how to find the reason. I did not find the similar posts in Stackoverflow.

Comment: first of all, that's a weird way of doing it, and i think that's why you are getting weird results. try debug it and see what the result is, is it <tr style=""background: green;""> or <tr style="background: green;"> when you include double quote

Comment: can't you just do <table>@if(a > 5)
{<tr style="background: green;">
 </tr>}<tr style="background: red;"></tr>
</table> nothing unexpected will come out.

Comment: You should include the double quotes.  I have no idea why it would have worked without them.

Comment: it might be a double quote single quote problem, try using single quote specialBackground = 'background: green;'; and include that in <tr style="@specialBackground">
 </tr>

Comment: @juharr Any official reference document to support what you said? Thanks.

Comment: @Mindless You have to use double quotes for the string because it's a C# string, but for the html code it can either have double or single quotes but there has to be quotes or it will be `<tr style=background: green;>` which is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave the double (or single if you prefer) quotes in your view

```
<table>
 <tr style="@specialBackground">
 </tr>
</table>
```

And handle the string normally in the C# file.

Quotes are optional for HTML attributes but you should use them for consistency as they are necessary when you have a space in your attribute, as you have.

> Attributes are placed inside the start tag, and consist of a name and
>   a value, separated by an = character. The attribute value can remain
>   unquoted if it doesn’t contain spaces or any of " ' ` = < or >.
>   Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes.
>   The value, along with the = character, can be omitted altogether if
>   the value is the empty string.

Taken from: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values

Comment: If I did: <tr style="@specialBackground">. Which actual is <tr style=""background: green;"">? If yes, why """" (two double quotes) can work for adding a css class to style?

Comment: It doesn't work like that, in C# `string specialBackground = "background: green";` the double quotes aren't part of the actual string. They define the start and end of the string. So the HTML rendered from `<tr style="@specialBackground">` is `<tr style="background: green;">`. To include double quotes in a C# string you need to escape them, fore example `string str = "you can \"quote\" me on this";`